# What is a concise definition for electric potential?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, definition

What is a concise definition for electric potential?

I'm interested to know because there are many different definitions.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a scalar function whose gradient gives the force a charge would experience were it placed at a point. It is a function which measures the change in energy if a charge were to be brought from some reference point (where potential is set to zero) to that point, due to all the fields in space between them.

Answer (score 0):

Electric potential is the ability of a system to perform work on a charge. There do not have to be other charges in the system itself.

Answer (score 0):

I like to think of electric potential as "pressure".

By Ohm's law,

$$I = V/R$$

Here, $V$ is the potenial difference. The current carrying wire lets in more current, if the potential difference is *high*. As an analogy, think of fast flowing water due to difference in pressure at both ends of the tube. If the pressure difference is large, the flow speed of water too will be large.

Electric potential is kind of like pressure in a way.

Answer (score 0):

Electric potential is defined by the amount of work energy required to move a unit of electric charge from a reference point to a specific point in an electric field.